# PHP: ¿Qué código les parece más legible?

Tags: php

Este código funciona. Soy super fan del operador ternario y lo utilizo siempre que puedo para cosas simples, pero siendo sinceros, en expresiones largas como esta, suele ser un poco menos legible, aunque se separe en varias líneas de código

**Opción 1**. Mi código original

```
$signo = $tot ? "<=" : "=";
$formula = $tot ? "sum(pronosticos.marc*2 + pronosticos.nat*2 + pronosticos.dif) AS m" : "sum(pronosticos.marc*2 + pronosticos.dif) AS m";
```

**Opcion 2**. Con un if-else

```
if ($tot) {
  $signo    = "<=";
  $formula  = "sum((pronosticos.marc + pronosticos.nat)*2 + pronosticos.dif)";
} else {
  $signo    = "=";
  $formula  = "sum((pronosticos.marc)*2 + pronosticos.dif)";
}
```

Los dos funcionan igual. A mi me gusta más el primero, pero es un tema de legibilidad. ¿cuál les parece mejor y por qué?

Comment: Me quedo con el primero. Realmente la *legilibilidad* en este caso se debe principalmente a la variable `pronosticos`. Si usas una convención de nombre en inglés, por lo general encuentras nombres de variables más breves y además el código se internacionaliza. Tu variable tiene **11 caracteres**, si usas `forecast`, hablamos de 5 caracteres menos x 5 usos, o sea, 25 caracteres menos. Y, según el contexto, en vez de `pronosticos` o `forecast` podrías usar un nombre de variable  de una sola letra o dos o tres (eso depende del contexto, muchas veces se puede hacer eso sin afectar la comprensión).

Comment: Gracias pero entre `pronosticos` y `forecast` hay solo 3 caracteres, y no es tanto una variable, sino el nombre de una tabla. El código está construyendo el query. Me imagino que podría hacer algo en el select como `... pronosticos as pron`

Comment: Cierto, son 3 caracteres de diferencia... En cualquier caso, como ya dije, según el contexto puedes usar un alias, y ese alias puede ser simplemente `p`, `data` o cualquier otro. Si viene de un `SELECT` usar un alias corto no creo que dificulte la legilibilidad, ya que en el contexto no hay lugar a confusión alguna (viendo el `SELECT` ya se sabrá de qué se trata).

Comment: Se supone que esta es una pregunta basada en opiniones,  que raro que la gente en este caso no esta siendo agresiva y no hay puntos negativos ni tampoco se encuentra cerrada,  me estoy perdiendo de algo o hay un porque del porque esta pregunta esta siendo bien recibida?, no lo digo porque tenga algo en contra de la pregunta... si no que he visto casos de preguntas basadas en opiniones que han llegado a tener hasta 24 votos negativos y se encuentran cerradas (y contenian efectivamente codigo detras como este caso), es bastante injusto eso.

Comment: Probablemente porque la gente no está tan estresada y los guardianes de lo políticamente correcto de StackOverflow no han llegado y la pregunta es interesante y relevante. En el sitio en inglés hay *BASTANTES* al respecto sobre el estílo de código. Crei que sería interesante replicar lo mismo en español, que es una comunidad que requiere de mucho más movimiento

Answer (score 1):

Es opinable y depende el contexto. 
Esto es: si el contexto es que estás debbugueando, y (en tu debug) solamente te interesa hacer un seguimiento de la variable (por ejemplo) `$signo`, se me hace más fácil el primero.
Es más directo: ves la asignación de esa variable en particular en esa línea.

Si el contexto es que estás haciendo un seguimiento del código, o si querés debuggear que es lo que pasa cuando cambia la variable `$tot`, se me hace mucho más fácil y directo el segundo.

A veces yo elijo no usar else. En tu segundo ejemplo, usaría algo así:

```
$signo    = "=";
$formula  = "sum((pronosticos.marc)*2 + pronosticos.dif)";

if($tot) {
  $signo    = "<=";
  $formula  = "sum((pronosticos.marc + pronosticos.nat)*2 + pronosticos.dif)";
}
```

Y si querés que sea más específico, lo hubiera resuelto para que la implementación me quede así:

```
$total
->resolve(
   // Si hay total
)
->orElse(
   // Si no hubiera total
);
```

Para armarlo así, deberías armar una clase $total (en la cual, incluso podrías agregar cual es el cálculo de total), y 2 funciones que reciban lambda functions por parámetro: "resolve" y "orElse".
Es un poco más complicado, ¡pero más divertido! Y a mi gusto, el código queda mucho más verboso (mucho más legible).